# Why is my Yii2 app setting cookies and Cache-Control on Heroku in production but not locally?

Tags: php, apache, heroku, yii2

Why I try to see the headers set by my app, I see that it is setting a bunch of headers in production on Heroku, but not locally. I can't find where these headers are being set. There is nothing in a `.htaccess` file to set them, and nothing in the code.

#### Locally

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:81/xxxx/web/shopping/search?q=toaster
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2015 01:42:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.12
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

$ grep cache_limiter  /etc/php5/php.ini
session.cache_limiter = nocache
```

#### Heroku

```
$ curl -I http://xxxx.herokuapp.com/shopping/search?q=toaster
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2015 01:41:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1f
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.15
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=6s4ldkqggihqgb9gj2qvjcn4r0; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: search=2f4e7a0d06212f661972c07e76dbfa0f9e19c4db05c19e51bc48ae4652bff4b1a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A6%3A%22search%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A26%3A%22%2Fshopping%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dtoaster%22%3B%7D; path=/; httponly
Set-Cookie: _csrf=4fbe4972ee8c23b296f9673d3987cb1c4928a4bae193d411f4884e431351bdb0a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22_csrf%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22pe67duP6CFmncROecUjq-JQvCp9-Ho4M%22%3B%7D; path=/; httponly
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

Answer (score 1):

It was because I had `flush();` in my controller. Yii must set those headers at the end of the controller when it renders the view. My local version now outputs those same headers, but I still don't know where they are coming from. I have another question for that.

I don't know why it did not behave the same in production. All I can think of is that the PHP version is different and Heroku might have a more sophisticated FastCGI module or cache that ignores `flush()` or ignores blank lines in the HTTP headers.